# crossdomain.xml 401 error when accessing site when already authenticated

Tags: silverlight, single-sign-on, crossdomain.xml, unauthorized

I have a SingleSignOn solution in place from 1 domain to the other.

It is done by a silverlight app which sends an authenticated request to my other domain.

The problem I have is that when I go to the silverlight page, when I'm not logged on to the second domain yet, the SSO is done and I'm logged in to the second domain without any problem.

When I then, DON't log out, but perform the SSO again, I'm getting a **401 Not authorized** error on my **crossdomain.xml** file..

Anyone encountered a similar problem and knows whats going on?

Will provide extra info if needed, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was that only anonymous access to the file was allowed.
Setting `<location> <allow =? and =*` did not help.

The fix was to add Everyone to the permissions of the file and give them read access.